# Azure cloud services: Redirect existing x.cloudapp.net site without a machine running

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

Is there some way to redirect an existing x.cloudapp.net cloud service URL without having to have a machine deployed. I would like to find a free solution to this problem. I could of course deploy a minimal machine that does this and get away really cheap.

The reason I'm asking is that we're taking down an application that has been linked to by some of our partners using a cloudapp.net url, so just deleting the cloud service would break their links.

Comment: I hope this isn't possible, because the name of the cloudapp will become available to other Azure customers, therefore they might want to use this name and you shouldn't be allowed to make redirections on it. You could ask your customers to redirect the link to a different location, but this would be suboptimal. Best would be to create a small/free cloud service, so you can 'keep' this url. BTW: It's not a very good practice to expose these urls to customers, for reasons you have discovered just now.

Comment: Well, it doesn't become available until you delete the cloud service. You can keep it without having anything deployed. That was my idea.

Comment: True, I had assumed you were talking about removing the cloud service. I probably misunderstood this from the question.

Answer (score 0):

> Well, it doesn't become available until you delete the cloud service.

Yes, you could keep the sub domain without having anything deployed. But we can't do anything with the Cloud Service until we deploy any roles(Web Role or Worker Role) to it. All the setting panel shows "This slot has no deployment. Deploy roles to the slot to configure your cloud service."

The only way is deploying a minimal machine as your mentioned in your post.